# MVC 4 Calling an action asychronously

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC4 and Entity Framework to develop a wep app. In one of my views, I have a list of persons which all have details. At the beginning, only the first and last name are displayed but a link is available to show the details and I want to make it as dynamic as possible.

My action returns a `Json(object, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

Any idea guys?

EDIT : My action

```
        public ActionResult ListByOwner(long id)
    {
        var productallocations = db.ProductAllocations.Where(obj => obj.Id_Person == id).Include("Product");
        return PartialView(productallocations);
    }
```

My View :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <script src="../../Scripts/globalize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/globalize.culture.fr-FR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="brand" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">BuSI Material Manager</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
                    Logged in as @User.Identity.Name
                </p>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Home")</li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Persons <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("All persons list","Index","Person")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("All allocations list", "Index", "ProductAllocation")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cards<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("All phone cards list", "Index", "PhoneCard")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("All fuel cards list", "Index", "VehicleFuelCard")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("All products list", "Index", "Product")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Products in stock", "ProductStock", "Product")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Allocated products", "AllocatedProducts", "Product")</li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Product types", "Index", "ProductType")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Product companies", "Index", "ProductCompany")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Vehicles <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("All vehicles list", "Index", "Vehicle")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Available vehicles", "AvailableVehicles", "Vehicle")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Allocated vehicles", "AllocatedVehicles", "Vehicle")</li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vehicle types", "Index", "VehicleType")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vehicle motor types", "Index", "VehicleMotorType")</li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "VehicleInsuranceContract")">Insurance contracts</a></li>
                          <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "VehicleLeasingContract")">Leasing contracts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>Developed by me.</p>
        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        <script src="../../Scripts/Utils.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Bundles :

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use jquery to make an ajax request, then build some html from your json result of the action and insert it into the page. Personally I'd make the action return a partial view, and then the jquery would just receive the html and could insert it into the page directly.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea guys?

Yes, you could use an AJAX link:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Details", 
    "Details", 
    new { id = person.Id }, 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "details" }
)
```

and then have a placeholder where the details will be shown:

```
<div id="details"></div>
```

and finally have your controller action return a partial view instead of JSON:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var model = repository.Get(id);
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and in the corresponding partial view you could have the details:

```
@model Person
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FirstName)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.LastName)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Age)
</div>
...
```

Remark: don't forget to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script in your _Layout if you want the `Ajax.ActionLink` to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still does not work. I followed what you made and my ActionLink tries to redirect me to an other view (so there is an error displayed). I included the correct file in my Layout.

Comment: Make sure you have included `jquery.js` **before** `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`. Also if you are using ASP.NET MVC 4 be careful with the bundles if you are using them to avoid multiple inclusions of the same scripts.

Comment: I've updated my code : I think there is no problem with the bundles. Should I include my ajax.js in the body, after my jquery.js so?

Comment: You should first have `jquery.js` and then have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`. If you are saying that when you click on the Ajax.ActionLink, you don't get an AJAX call but a browser redirect you definitely have problems with the scripts.

Comment: Thanks. Should I post my bundles config to allow you to have a look?

Comment: Now that you have shown your Layout it is clear what the problem is. You have included `jquery.js` **after** `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` not **before** as you should. Get rid of this `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script inclusion from the `<head>` section and put it **after** `jquery.js` at the end. Or just include the `~/bundles/jqueryval` bundle after the `~/bundles/jquery` bundle.

Comment: I swear that I have followed your instructions but it is not working. I included the jqueryval right after the jquery bundle and it still redirects me to my partial view which seems to be a simple view.